# Python - How to Grab Azure Continuation Token?

Tags: python, azure, azure-table-storage

I'm trying to query table storage from Microsoft Azure using Python. I've been using this library: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/azure-storage/0.20.3

Querying table storage hasn't been too difficult, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to grab the continuation token. I've seen several c# examples, and even a Java example, but not a single one for Python.

Here's my method that grabs one thousand entries while using the 'top' parameter. Under this condition I should have a continuation token within the response. Per this documentation:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd135718.aspx

```
    def get_thousand_chunk(self, filter, select, top, next_partition_key, next_row_key):
    print "Getting table storage..."
    list = self.table_service.query_entities(self.table_name, top=1000)
    #result.x_ms_continuation['NextPartitionKey']
    '''
    ---LIBRARY DOCUMENTATION WITHIN query_entities METHOD---

    Get entities in a table; includes the $filter and $select options.

    table_name:
        Table to query.
    filter:
        Optional. Filter as described at
        http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd894031.aspx
    select:
        Optional. Property names to select from the entities.
    top:
        Optional. Maximum number of entities to return.
    next_partition_key:
        Optional. When top is used, the next partition key is stored in
        result.x_ms_continuation['NextPartitionKey']
    next_row_key:
        Optional. When top is used, the next partition key is stored in
        result.x_ms_continuation['NextRowKey']
    '''

    print "Got table storage"
    return self._mapper(list)
```

Obviously this code is a work in progress, and so I have `top=1000` hard coded as a parameter in the method call for testing purposes. I also realize that I'm not currently using `next_partition_key` or `next_row_key` However, I am open to all constructive criticism.

Please let me know if you need more information to appropriately answer.

Thank you all in advance.

I am using Python 2.7.8.

Answer (score 3):

Please try the following code:

```
import os
import json
from azure import *
from azure.storage import *
from azure.storage.table import TableService, Entity

table_service = TableService(account_name='account-name', account_key='account-key')
list = table_service.query_entities('table-name', top=100)
if hasattr(list, 'x_ms_continuation'):
    nextPartitionKey = list.x_ms_continuation['NextPartitionKey']
    nextRowKey = list.x_ms_continuation['NextRowKey']
    print nextPartitionKey
    print nextRowKey
```

Ref: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/blob/master/azure/storage/table/tableservice.py (check documentation for `query_entities` function)

Comment: This is the answer. Thank you!

Comment: See the tests as well (https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/blob/master/tests/test_storage_table.py#L638). Also to note: We're doing a major refactor of this library and the upcoming version will automatically (and lazily) follow continuation tokens for you. :)

Comment: @EmilyGerner is there a new version for this?

Answer (score 0):

As of 2023 below is a working code example

package

```
pip install azure-cosmosdb-table
```

Code

```
next_partition_key = None
next_row_key = None

loop = True

while loop:
    # Query all entities in the table
    entities = table_service.query_entities(table_name,  marker={'nextpartitionkey': next_partition_key, 'nextrowkey': next_row_key}
    )

    loop = False

    if len(entities.next_marker) > 0:
        next_partition_key = entities.next_marker['nextpartitionkey']
        next_row_key = entities.next_marker['nextrowkey']
        loop = True
```